# Optimal sort algorithm in number of swaps

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

Given a sequence of $n$ numbers, can it be sorted with $O(n \ln n)$ comparisons and $O(n)$ swaps/moves? Any pointer to publications on that matter or counterarguments showing a $\Omega(n \ln n)$ lower bound would help.

Comment: Any comparison based sorting algorithm will need to perform $\Omega(n \log n)$ comparisons and $\Omega(n)$ swaps in the worst case (cf. CLRS).

Comment: Trivially, you can achieve $O(n)$ moves if you first sort a table that contains the indexes of the elements, and only after that sort the table that contains the elements.

Comment: @jukka well that's cheating coz you moved elements when you sorted the table ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There exists a stable in-place sorting algorithm with $O(n \log n)$ comparisons and $O(n)$ moves.

See:
Gianni Franceschini: Sorting Stably, in Place, with $O(n \log n)$ Comparisons and $O(n)$ Moves. Theory Comput. Syst. 40(4): 327-353 (2007)
http://www.springerlink.com/content/d7348168624070v7/