# Stable comparison sort with $O(1)$ auxiliary memory and $O(n \log n)$ average running time

Tags: ds.algorithms, sorting

Does there exist a stable comparison sort using $O(1)$ auxiliary memory and achieving $O(n \log n)$ average run time?

Context: There are comparison sorts with any two of those three desirable characteristics (see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)). Is there a reason why the three cannot be achieved simultaneously? *[Edit: I added the algorithm from the accepted answer to the list on Wikipedia, obviously it wasn't there when I asked the question.]*

Comment: See the answer of this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/optimal-sort-algorithm-in-number-of-swaps/7250#7250

Comment: @Snowie "in-place" typically means with space $O(\log n)$, doesn't it?

Comment: @JɛﬀE I don't think that is true for most (in-place) versions of Quicksort, e.g. Sedgewick's: you inadvertantly change the order of duplicates. You would have to break the tie when directly comparing the two elements (which happens iff one is selected as pivot, i.e. later if at all) but by then positions are skrewed (unless you want to store the original indices; that would cost $O(n)$ memory).

Comment: @Snowie: Unless Raphael's objection holds, please post http://www.springerlink.com/content/d7348168624070v7/ as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: I agree with Rapheal.  "In-place" means that there is only a constant number of addition locations to store elements, but each element requires $O(\log n)$ bits to describe.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` in a [comment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/36574) above is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/s00224-006-1311-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00224-006-1311-1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a sort algorithm with $O(1)$ auxiliary *words* and achieving $O(n\log n)$ worst-case run time, where $n$ is the length of the input array.
http://www.springerlink.com/content/d7348168624070v7/

I don't think that the question seeks an algorithm with $O(1)$ auxiliary *bits*, because such algorithm must be *tricky*.  I mean, if we cannot use even $O(\log n)$ bits, then we cannot use a simple for-loop (for(i=0, i < n, i++) {...} ) in the algorithm without introducing variable i (which require additional $O(\log n)$ bits).

Comment: OK, makes perfect sense. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/s00224-006-1311-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00224-006-1311-1).