# Open questions about linear-time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, time-complexity, nondeterminism, time-hierarchy

What are some interesting open or solved-but-hard questions around problems having linear-time solutions?  Ala [riffle shuffles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/linear-time-in-place-riffle-shuffle-algorithm).

I'm especially curious about problems which people believe to be linear-time but for which either no linear-time algorithm is known or for which finding one proved difficult.

As a technical matter, I'm perhaps most interested in weak-linear-time on a single-tape nondeterministic machine, but other linear-time models are still interesting, ala deterministic or multi-tape models.  I'm aware that strong-linear-time on a single tape nondeterministic machine is regular, hence linear-time on a single-tape deterministic machine is regular too.

Comment: [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) algorithm. From Wikipedia: *... Whether the problem can be solved deterministically in linear time by a comparison-based algorithm remains an open question ...*. See also this [question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/powerful-algorithms-too-complex-to-implement) for a couple of "hard to implement" linear time algorithms.

Comment: What is "weak" (or, for that matter, "strong") linear time?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: Your comment should be an answer!

Comment: So, are you interested in algorithms (described in a random-access model of computation) or complexity results (framed in terms of Turing machines)?

Comment: Yeah, Marzio's comment answer is plenty to keep me chugging along here, thank you!